# CLI references wrong npm version

Tags: windows, node.js, npm, command-line-interface

1. Installed node.js v0.10.29 with .msi (includes npm v1.4.14)
2. `npm install -g npm` (updating npm to v1.4.20)
3. `npm -v`: v1.4.14 (located in `c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm`)
4. npm v1.4.20 is located in `c:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm`
5. `echo %path`:

   > C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;**C:\Program Files\nodejs**;C:\Ruby200-x64\bin;C:\python27

   - Removing the bold part leaves me with `sh.exe": npm: command not found`
   - Adding `%AppData%\npm\node_modules` doesn't fix it

6. Adding `NODE_PATH` to system wide environment variables with `%AppData\npm\node_modules` is not helping

The problem is essentially that it refuses to recognize the global npm installation in `%AppData%\npm\node_modules` even when I remove `C:\Program Files\nodejs` from the path and replace it with `%AppData%\npm\node_modules`.

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this?

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong.  It's because computers suck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After opening this issue on [joyent/node](https://github.com/joyent/node), [this reply](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/7986#issuecomment-49904817) suggests **using the Node.js command prompt** as a temporary workaround.

**Preparation**:

- Remove `C:\Program Files\nodejs` from any environment variables
- Add a environment variable called `NODE_PATH` with this value: `%AppData%\npm\node_modules`
- Check your `.npmrc` file (Windows: `C:\Users\[User]\.npmrc`)

  If the value for `prefix` is `c:\Program Files\nodejs`, add `prefix = c:\Users\[User]\AppData\Roaming\npm` to the user config area (at the top of the file)

**After this:**

1. Start Menu > All Programs > Node.js > **Node.js command prompt**
2. `npm -v`: 1.4.14
3. `npm install -g npm`
4. `npm -v`: 1.4.21

Comment: I wonder if remove the installation directory from PATH and other environment variables, whether you can still use "node" command from a standard prompt or CLI like powershell?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, a safe and error free node.js on windows, can be achieved if you install it in `"C:\nodejs\"` instead of installing it in `ProgramFiles` or any other directory because of some read/write permissions.

For the question...

go to cmd and run

```
npm install -g npm
```

and copy "npm" folder from

C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules

```
//first npm is the installed version and then npm modules are its
// modules installed one of them is your new npm that is the result
// of above command. we are copying it to its insaller. the father :P
```

Paste this copied "npm" folder into this path and overwrite if it asks

```
 C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules
```

check your verison it will be latest. by

```
npm -v //in cmd
```

Answer (score 2):

If using Windows 7 or later, try:

```
move "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm.bak"
mklink /D "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm" "%AppData%\npm\node_modules\npm"
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your path environment variable. My guess is that it lists both the program files and the appdata directories, and the program files location is listed first. The first one found on the path is the one that will run.

Comment: That's not the case. Updated question with the value of `Path`.

Comment: Where did you get that path variable? There's actually two - the system level path and the per-user path. That looks like just the per-user path. What do you get if you open a cmd.exe prompt and type echo %path%

Comment: I've updated the question again. Could you please have a look?